# Newcastle is keen to enhance its already strong standing among students both at home and abroad

Tags: meaning, expressions, phrase-meaning

Q1. Have I understood correctly? Thank you :)

> A. Newcastle is keen to enhance its already strong standing among **students both at home and abroad**.

**= students who are in the UK and students who are abroad/overseas**

> B. Newcastle is keen to enhance its already strong standing among **students both from home and abroad**.

The phrases may be similar to those in some of my previous posts, but the questions are actually different. :)
**= students who are from the UK and students who are from abroad/overseas**

Q2. Do C and D mean the same thing? If so, what do they refer to? A or B? Thank you :)

> C. Newcastle is keen to enhance its already strong standing among **both domestic and international students**.
>
> D. Newcastle is keen to enhance its already strong standing among **students both domestically and internationally**.

The phrases may be similar to those in some of my previous posts, but the questions are actually different. However, I will avoid asking a similar question in a new post next time. My apologies and thank you so much for your great patience with a new member. Thank you :)

Comment: They all amount to the same thing, although worded differently.

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the original?

Comment: Thank you for your answers, Yosef Baskin and Mari-Lou A! (By the way, thank you for making my previous post visually appealing. I just followed suit) However, it seems to me there is a subtle difference between A and B, but I am not sure if I have understood correctly. I have changed my wording this time to make myself clearly understood :D

Comment: Students at home = students in the UK. Students abroad = students who are abroad (outside of England). It is the same as your last question (meaning A).

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, Clare! However, an American told me that... Normally "at home and abroad" talks about where you do something. We don't use "at" to mean "from" or "who live in".  I am getting confused... thank you :)

Comment: Given that the implied context is that Newcastle [University] is attempting to attract both UK-based students ["at home"] and foreign students ["abroad"], where different levels of funding apply, it might be a case of "follow the money!"  As Willie Sutton said, when asked why he robbed banks, "because that's where the money is."

Comment: @Chinese- Over the past five days, you have asked five practically identical questions, or at least questions with the same essential concept, all of which have been poorly received here, in the form of down-votes and votes to close.  Allow me to strongly encourage you to think about your real source of concern, consolidate the core of that into a single question, then post that single question at our companion site, https://ell.stackexchange.com/.  Good luck to you, I hope you do stick with the Stack Exchange Network in some form.

Comment: Thank you so much for your further clarification, Robin!  Thank you :)

Comment: @cobaltduck Yes, you are right. I am so sorry for asking so many similar questions in a row on this site! I will make sure to think about my real source of concern and  consolidate the core of that into a single question before posting it. Thank you :)

Comment: Thank you all for your replies! Problem solved thanks to your help :D

Comment: Yes, but some questions have remained unsolved ... that's why I asked again. Thank you and my apologies! :)

Comment: Are you saying there is a difference in meaning between  ***…at*** *home and abroad* compared to ***…from*** *home and abroad.*? Their meanings are identical, you have clearly understood but I'd prefer the preposition **at**.   "Domestic and International students" is  paraphrasing the original sentence, so A, B, and C mean exactly the same. However, I would avoid using *among* and *both* together in the same sentence, i.e. `strong standing among both domestic...`. Instead  use either `between domestic and international students…` or `both domestic and international students…`